# Camel/Quarkus - AdviceWith can't find route by id

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I have the following route:

```java
from("direct:someRoute")
.id("someRoute")
.log(...)
.to("sql-stored:someProcedure(BIGINT ${exchangeProperty.someVal})")
.id("someCall")
.log(...)
.end()
```

I am attempting to replace the `someCall` REST call with canned data for tests.

I have setup my tests as such:

```java
@QuarkusTest
public Class Tests{

    @Inject
    CamelContext camelContext

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(){
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(
            this.camelContext,
            "someRoute",
            a -> {
                a.weaveById("someCall")
                    .replace()
                    .setBody()
                    .constant("{}")
            }
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne(){
        //...
    }
    @Test
    public void testTwo(){
        //...
    }
}
```

However, when I run the tests, I get the following errors:

- First test error:

  - `Cannot advice route as route with id: someRoute does not exists`
- Second test error:

  - `There are no outputs with matches: someCall in the route: <routeToString, oddly with no mention of the someCall route, or even an sql route>`

Seem like strange errors to me, looking through the logs and the route is definitely being picked up, and even stranger that the `someCall` reference isn't in the toString...

### Update

Just realized that this occurrs in tests *after* the first one. It seems that my issue is related to the face that this is in an `@BeforeEach`... Should I rework to only be called once, or is there a way to reset the camel context before re-applying the mock?

### Update 2

Tried calling `context.stop()` and `context.start()` at the beginning of the tests, but got an error saying it is unsupported.

Trying with `CamelQuarkusTestSupport` ended up with the first test working out, but every additional test having an empty `CamelQuarkus` with no routes...

Comment: The root cause is probably the injected CamelContext which seems to be an empty one (with no route at all). Put a breakpoint an examine the contents of `camelContext` variable

Comment: After a bit  of debugging, I have found what looks like a fully fleshed out Camel Context with the routes I would expect

Comment: Realized that it works, but only once. Updated the question

Comment: See the IMPORTANT note at: https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html#_enabling_advice_during_testing

Comment: I have seen that, but was honestly unsure of the applicability in Quarkus, esp. since `@AdviceWith` doesn't seem present.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you should set the ID as:

```
.routeId("someRoute")
```